# build-in release variables and variable groups in YAML release stages

Tags: azure-devops

In the UI (classic) Release pipelines, there are build-in variables like $(Release.EnvironmentName), which changes depending on which stage you are at.

Is there an equivalent when using a YAML pipeline?

Also in the classis mode variable groups are automatically scoped to the stage if there are linked, is this also possible in YAML somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. The usage of the predefined variable in Yaml pipeline is the same with classic pipeline. `$(Release.EnvironmentName)` is for [classic release pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch).  You can refer to variables `$(System.StageName)` or `$(Environment.Name)` in the yaml pipeline.

Click the links to find more predefined [build variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) to learn more about variables in yaml pipeline.

> For variable groups scoped to stage in classic release  pipeline

It is possible in Yaml pipeline. In yaml you can scope your variable groups in job or stage by define variables under job or stage in yaml. For below example.

1,Variables scoped to stage Build:

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  variables:
      - group: SourceMessage 
  jobs:
  - job: A            
- stage: release     
  jobs:
  - job: B
```

2, Variables scoped to all stages:

```
stages:
variables:
  - group: SourceMessage 
- stage: Build 
  jobs:
  - job: A            
- stage: release     
  jobs:
  - job: B
```

3, Variables scoped to job A:

```
stages:
- stage: Build 
  jobs:
  - job: A  
    variables:
    - group: SourceMessage 
- stage: release     
  jobs:
  - job: B
```

Comment: I tried using the variable $(Release.EnvironmentName)
but it doesnt seem to work.

The YAML i used:

  `- stage: Deploy_Development   
    jobs:
    - deployment: Development_Deploy
      environment: 
        name: Development
        resourceType: VirtualMachine
        tags: dev
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - powershell: |
                  Write-Host '$(Release.EnvironmentName)'`

Comment: Your 2nd scenario doesnt work:
"2, Variables scoped to all stages:"

Comment: You can try $(Environment.Name) for [deployment job variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#deployment-job-variables), Or $(System.StageName) for [system variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables)

Comment: I can confirm that  `$(Environment.Name)` maps to the `environment:` key, and `$(System.StageName)` maps to the `stage:` key